# How to submit a multipart form with Goutte / Guzzle

Tags: php, symfony, multipartform-data, guzzle, goutte

Trying to test a form that does image uploads and has a few hidden fields which looks like this:

```
<form class="add" action="https://example.com/stSPyOCwDVg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="tokenCode" value="U2FsdGVkX18zMTY1MjMxNuUCJfrsNa-cT0yap3xGbgrDN6RkCLpTbOm8JLusrW1vGGQxqAdYYdE">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
    <button class="addbtn" type="submit" name="go">add image</button>
</form>
```

Was expecting a submit similar to non-multipart forms but that's not the case. Instead trying a POST as follows:

```
// load the form page
$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/form');

// uploading params and files as per docs
$form = $crawler->selectButton('add image')->form(); // locate the upload form by button name
$post_url = $form->getUri();  // 'action' attrib on the form
$params = $form->getValues(); // grab hidden fields
$files = ['/tmp/UL_img1', '/tmp/UL_img2', '/tmp/UL_img3'];
$crawler = $client->request('POST', $post_url, $params, $files);

echo $crawler->html();
```

This just returns the original form and no files are uploaded. Does anyone know if this is being called correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal soln but this actually works:

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('add image')->form();
$files = ['/tmp/UL_img1', '/tmp/UL_img2', '/tmp/UL_img3']
foreach($files as $file) {
    $form['file'] = $tmpfname; // this was key
    $browser = $client->submit($form);
}
```

Basically the filename can be assigned to the 'file' input. This way we don't have to worry about the correct POST url / hidden attribs / cookeis are being sent along with the request.

Multiple files in the same request doesn't work yet. Will update.